# Compare 2 text file contents in c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 text file in C# say: `File - A` & `File - B`. I want to compare both file contents and if there is any content found in `File - A` which is not present in `File - B` then i want to put that content in File - B at the same location where it is in `File - A`.

```
   File - A                                        File - B

This is the example text.                         This is text.
```

Now if we compare above 2 file contents then the output should be :

```
                           File - B

                       This is the example text.
```

So if is there any method in c# which can do this for me then please let me know?

Comment: Do you need to do this in code or can you shell out to the command line can call BeyondCompare or WinMerge or similar?

Comment: So why not replacing the whole file B's content with the content of File A?

Comment: @TimSchmelter its a good thought, but only if it will not remove the other contents present in the File - B which is not present in File - A

Comment: @KingKong: To be precise, you want to replace the content of file B with that of File A without removing content of file B that is not present in File A, correct? How to handle the case that there's content in A on line 10 and in File B there's content on line 10 that is not in File A? What will win?

Comment: Thats why i ask this question @TimSchmelter

Comment: @KingKong We can help you solve your problem, but you'll need to know how the problem should be solved.  Defining your requirements isn't something we can really help with.

Comment: @KingKong: You are the only one who knows what rules are applicable.

Comment: I told every rule from my side but if there is any, which u think that i missed or u want to know then please ask me @TimSchmelter

Comment: @KingKong Ok, line 1 of File - A is "Hello World". Line 1 of File - B is "Fubar". What should the first line of the file you want be? Should line 1 be "Hello World" and line 2 be "Fubar" or should line 1 be "Hello World Fubar"?

Comment: Anything sameline or differentline no worry about that, but both must be in the output file (File -B) @seekerOfKnowledge

Comment: @KingKong are all the words separated the same way, as in a space or a comma?

Comment: Also, do you need to preserve duplicate words?

Comment: Took a stab at your problem without your answers. When you get a chance to provide more requirements, I'll be happy to adjust the code as needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
var f1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\l1.txt");
var f2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\l3.txt");

var result = f1.Select((l, index) => new {Number= index, Text = l})
  .Join(f2.Select((l, index) => new {Number= index, Text = l}), 
        inner => inner.Number, 
        outer => outer.Number, 
        (inner, outer) =>  {
        if(inner.Text == "")
            return outer.Text;
        return inner.Text;
  })
  .Concat(f1.Where((l, index) => index >= f2.Count()))
  .Concat(f2.Where((l, index) => index >= f1.Count()));
  //.Dump();

File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\l3.txt", result);
```

This will compare line by line, if the line of the first file is empty, will keep the line of the seconde file, otherwhise always print the first file line....

Then we concat the result with the lines left of both files.

Comment: If the line in the first file is empty, keep second line. What if the line in the second file is different than the line in the first file? I think he wants to keep the line in the second file. Maybe he wants to add the line from the first file before or after the line in the second file. These maybes need answers. OP, help!

Comment: Well the question was kinda of vague, I answered as I understood it :)...if he wants to add the line after o before, well, that's merging files like windiff, kdiff, and stuff like that, and this doesn't fix it, maybe with a select many and play with an anonymous class with the index....well, let's wait for any more information

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a full set of requirements, but here.

```
string[] fileAWords = File.ReadAllText("C:\\File - A.txt").Split(' ');
string[] fileBWords = File.ReadAllText("C:\\File - B.txt").Split(' ');

// The comparer makes it so the union is case insensitive
// For example: Welcome in File - A and welcome (lower-case) in File - B in a Union would both be in the result
// With the comparer, it will only appear once.
IEnumerable<string> allWords = fileAWords.Union(fileBWords, new StringEqualityComparer());

// We did the split on a space, so we want to put the space back in when we join.
File.WriteAllText("C:\\File - C.txt", string.Join(" ", allWords));
```

The StringEqualityComparer class code is:

```
class StringEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    // Lower-case your strings for a case insensitive compare.
    public bool Equals(string s1, string s2)
    {
        if (s1.ToLower().Equals(s2.ToLower()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    #region IEqualityComparer<string> Members
    public int GetHashCode(string s)
    {
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 string fileAContent = File.ReadAllText(fileAPath);
 string fileBContent = File.ReadAllText(fileBPath);

 string[] fileAWords = filesAContent.split(_your delimiters_);
 string[] fileBWords = filesBContent.split(_your delimiters_);

 if (fileAWords.Except(fileBWords).Length > 0)
 {
    // there are words in file B that are not in file A
 }
```

If you want to optimize performance you can add all of the words in fileAWords in a HashSet and then iterate though all fileBWords and check if there is a work that not exists in the hashset

Answer (score 1):

A simple LINQ approach:

```
var file1 = File.ReadLines(path1);
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines(path2);
var onlyInFileA = file1.Except(file2);
File.WriteAllLines(path2, file2.Concat(onlyInFileA));
```