# File Monitoring and changes

Tags: c#

I want to write program that monitors file continuously and give me the updated things like adding a line ,deleting a line ,modifications in a line using c#. i did with file monitoring,how to know the updated things. Pleas help me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a real question for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Like @Soner Gönül said, you did not make much effort to write your question and I believe this will be closed soon. There are a few links with other questions where you can get some inspiration.

As I believe you will need to do some comparison every time you check the changes, read the answers of these other questions:

(there are a few examples using linq that might help you)

[Compare two text files line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370070/compare-two-text-files-line-by-line)

[Compare 2 text file contents in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915308/compare-2-text-file-contents-in-c-sharp)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ad07af87-4664-4475-a820-d77c756a93f7

Also this example from Microsof Support tells you how to create a File-Compare function:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320348